# Sorting a **Matrix structure

Tags: c, sorting, matrix, dynamic, bubble-sort

I would sort(ascending/descending doesn't matter) a **matrix structure in C, I have already tried with this sorting(bubble sort) function below, but seems that don't work. What is wrong? There are some other efficient/clear ways to sort a matrix? thanks :-)

```
void sortMatrix(int **matrix,int nrow,int ncol)
{
    int i, j;
    int temp;

    temp=0;

    i=0;
    while( i <nrow)
    {
        j=0;
        while (j < ncol-1)
        {
            //printf("Matrix pos:[%d,%d] val:%d and matrix pos:[%d,%d] val: %d\n", i,j, matrix[i][j], i,j+1, matrix[i][j+1]);
            if(matrix[i][j] < matrix[i][j+1])
            {

                temp= matrix[i][j];
                matrix[i][j]=  matrix[i][j+1];
                matrix[i][j]= temp;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

This is the main, the matrix is allocated dynamically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include"MatrixIO.h"

int main(void) {

    int **matrix= NULL;
    //int i, j;
    int nrow, ncol;

    //i= j= 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("inser NxM size\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &nrow, &ncol);

    matrix= allocMatrix(matrix, nrow, ncol);

    fillRandMatrix(matrix, nrow, ncol);
    printMatrix(matrix, nrow, ncol);

    printf("Sorted:\n");
    sortMatrix(matrix, nrow, ncol);
    printMatrix(matrix, nrow, ncol);


    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT:

the elements in the matrix should be sorted from the smallest to the biggest

```
34 12  2 21 98  >>>>>  2  12 21 23 33 
24 45 69 98 777 >>>>> 34 45 69 98 777
```

Comment: Step 1 is to define what you mean by sorting a matrix. Are you sorting the elements in each row, and then sorting the rows by their first elements, or are you moving the smallest element in the whole matrix to the first row/first col?

Comment: OT: The variables for rows and columns should be be of `size_t`, as well as the counters `i` and `j`.

Comment: @user3386109 true, I would sorting the matrix elements from the smallest to the biggest, I added an example.

Comment: @CSDude you are now asking a different question "how do I?" which has changed from your "what's wrong with?"

Comment: In that case, you can simply treat the matrix as a 1D array and sort it with `qsort`. I'll let @WeatherVane add that to the answer, if so inclined.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an error in the swapping

```
temp= matrix[i][j];
matrix[i][j]=  matrix[i][j+1];
matrix[i][j]= temp;
```

should be

```
temp= matrix[i][j];
matrix[i][j]=  matrix[i][j+1];
matrix[i][j+1]= temp;               // <--- j+1
```

**EDIT**

The sort also fails since the `j` loop can start before the `i` loop and reverse a previous swap. But it's quite unclear in what way you are trying to sort. Assuming you are trying to sort each row:

```
for (k=0; k<nrow; k++) {
    for (i=0; i<ncol-1; i++) {                      //<--- stops with room for j
        for (j=i+1; j<ncol; j++) {                  //<--- starts at i+1
            if(matrix[k][j] < matrix[k][i]) {
                temp= matrix[k][i];
                matrix[k][i]=  matrix[k][j];
                matrix[k][j]= temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right..the swapping was totally wrong, your function is ok to sort each row, but what if I should sorting all elements from the smallest to the biggest one? thanks